# HTML- <base> tag that works for more than just one document

Tags: html, url, path

I'm running an HTML/CSS/JS site (I'm not using PHP as the host I'm using doesn't support PHP). I'm trying to maintain two copies of the website: a local copy stored on my computer so that I can test any new changes I might want to make before putting the website up, and the official copy that's used on the website.

The problem is that whenever I finish making a change on the local copy, I need to go to each .html file and edit the links so that they work for the official copy. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/<username>/Documents/Programs/refs/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

needs to be changed to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/refs/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is very time consuming, as I would estimate I have around 15 different pages and I have to change the links for each one of them.

I've heard of the `<base>` tag, which changes the base URL for each link on the document. So I could use

```
<base href="C:/Users/<username>/Documents/Programs/">
```

for the local copy and

```
<base href="https://www.example.com/">
```

for the official one.

However, the `<base>` tag only works for one document, so in order to update my official copy, I would have to change the `<base>` tag on each document.

Is there a way to make the `<base>` tag work for more than one HTML file (like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does for PHP), or another way so that I can change all the `<base>` tags by only editing one file (e.g. a JavaScript file)? Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of [Relative links](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)?

Based on where is the file you are running you can retrieve resources in different directories starting from where the html file is stored.

So, if your html file is in

> C:/Users//Documents/Programs/

or

> https://www.example.com/

you can just put

```html
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="refs/style.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've heard of relative links, but my issue is that I also have documents that are stored in different folders (e.g. index.html and blog/index.html)

Comment: Well, with relative links you can go back in folders (../ goes to the previous folder and you can play with it, ../folder gets in a subfolder inside the parent folder, ecc)